# extract blocks of text from xml file

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have a file with these contents:

```
<People>
    <Person>
       <Name>Joe Blogs</Name>
       <Address>55 Oxford St</Address>
       ...lots of other properties
    </Person>
    <Person>
       <Name>Jane Pearson</Name>
       <Address>100 Samson St</Address>
       ...lots of other properties
    </Person>
</People>
```

The only tools I can use are: awk, sed, grep, pcre_grep

I would like to extract the content of each "Person" tag, remove the "Name" line, and calculate the md5 of the block.

So far I've tried:

```
awk '/<Person>/,/<\/Person>/{print $0}' input.xml | md5sum
```

However that only returns a single md5. Not one for each block.

Comment: Is the formatting of the file fixed? Or can the whitespace vary?

Comment: What do you actually need? To print the blocks or to get a separate md5sum for them? The title and tags of your question suggest the former but it looks like the only problem is the `md5sum` which has nothing to do with the method you use to print the blocks. Also, can you use `perl`? What system is this running on?

Comment: Hi guys, the formatting is fixed, otherwise I wouldn't use sed/awk. Unfortunately the vintage of the linux distro I'm using doesn't have nice xml parsers. Even xmllint is old (pre --xpath).

Comment: In essence I would like to see if there are duplicate blocks (without considering the <name> line)

Comment: Unfortunately no perl

Comment: @Fidel, do you have java on this machine? If yes, xalan is the tool you search for

Comment: What do you mean by remove name line? did your grep support `-P` param? Is python installed on your system?

Comment: @Fidel you're using a Linux with no Perl? What distribution is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following awk-script:

```
awk '
/<Person>/,/<\/Person>/{
    if (! /<Name>/)
        a=a s $0
    s="\n"
    }
/<\/Person>/{
    system("echo \""a"\" |md5sum - ")
    a=s=""
    }' input.xml
```

Explanation:

- Collect all lines between tags `Person` into `a` variable
- When meet closing tag `/Person` call system command than empty `a` variable

Answer (score 1):

using sed as follows

```
 sed -n  '/^ *<Person> *$/,/^ *<\/Person> *$/{/<Name>/{d};p}' file|md5sum
```

target all lines in  `*<Person> *$/,/^ *<\/Person> *`.

`/<Name>/` check to see if the range has the tag "Name" and then delete this line. Afterwards print the lines ranges and pipe to md5sum